# jQuery AJAX failing with 404 on a 200 success response

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax

I have a simple API, written in Rails, which should be used with AJAX from jQuery.

Here is how my controller method looks like:

```
  user = User.find_by_email_and_password(params[:email], params[:password])
  if ! user
    user = User.new
    user.email = params[:email]
    user.password = params[:password]
    user.save
  end

  respond_with user, status: 200
```

This is the AJAX handler:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Service.url + 'login.json',
    data: {
      email: 'email@server.com',
      password: 'pass'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      if (json.id) {
        this.is_logged_in = true;
        this.data = json;
        $('#finilizeModal').modal('show');
        return $('#signInModal').modal('hide');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
      return alert('An error occured while executing AJAX request');
    },
    complete: function() {}
  });
```

The following just alerts: `An error occured while executing AJAX request` and has an error code of 404. But the Chrome Inspector shows that the request was successful and the output is a valid JSON.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any clues in `xhr` or `status` arguments to the `error` callback? Try printing each of them with `console.log()`

Comment: As I mentioned above the returned status by the error handler is 404

Comment: But what about `xhr`, sometimes I've seen helpful output in the internal status properties of the `xhr` argument

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate page without '.json' in rails, because: URL in rails '/somepage?email=emsil&password=pass.json', jQuery send '/somepage.json?email=email&password=pass'.